# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Tengo mi proyecto web a modo de ejemplo, uno básico para poder aprender mas sobre spring web, y cuando quiero levantar para hacer las pruebas (con servidor glassfish) me da error, (del servidor no, porque lo uso con otro proyecto) y no entiendo la verdad

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Info:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Info:   Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Warning:   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
Severe:   Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
```

mi dispatcher:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.agend.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Probé agregando un

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
```

pero igual salía el error.

Comment: Hola Sebas, parece que estás usando una excepción que no es válida, podrías mostrarnos el código que la incluye?.